# Get fresh SOLR results, not from cache

Tags: caching, solr, cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise

The query is send to solr is below:

`http://1.2.3.4:8983/solr/data.results/select?q=*:*&fq=date:[2016-01-01T00:00:00Z TO 2015-01-31T23:59:59Z]&sort=publishdate desc&wt=json&indent=true`

This gives me 10 results. Now of those 10 results, I update the latest record as `isdeleted=true` and I pass a query to Solr `&fq=-isdeleted:true`. But it still gives me same 10 results as before. Now in the date range, I change start range to `2016-01-02T00:00:00Z` instead of `2016-01-01T00:00:00Z` `(fq=date:[2016-01-02T00:00:00Z TO 2015-01-31T23:59:59Z]`), then the latest record which is set to true does not shows up. I guess my output of `[2016-01-01T00:00:00Z TO 2015-01-31T23:59:59Z]` has got saved in the cache and hence it is showing the same results. This has been occuring repeadtedly, I have tried with many different queries. How can I refresh the cache so that I get the latest updated records? Is there any configuration change to make in solr so as to always get the latest updated records?

Comment: This is probably not about cache but rather about indexing throughput. Does the value show up after some time? Whats your max autocommit set to?

Comment: `<autoSoftCommit><maxTime>10000</maxTime></autoSoftCommit>`

Comment: the value also does not show up after some time, I tried checking after 4 hours, still old record.